# C# TPL Multiple List Enumerators One Modifier Without Starvation

Tags: c#, locking, task-parallel-library

I have several threads created through the TPL (probably not relevant).  Some threads interact with a particular object by simply enumerating over a contained List without ever modifying anything.  Other threads add or remove items from the List.  Currently, I have lock statement around all code segments that enumerate the List and lock statements around all code segments that modify the List.

I'm not experiencing any performance problems so that's that.  However, I do realize that the more-efficient solution would be to allow many concurrent enumerators and only lock out everything else when modifying the List.  Currently, only one thread may be enumerating the List at any given time.  For future reference, what is the pattern that allows this?

**Important**.  There are many solutions that work fine in a lot of cases but most likely won't work for mine.  In my application, there is a good chance that the barrage of readers will never stop -- thus starving all the modifiers.  I'm looking for:

```
Enumerate 1
Enumerate 2 Concurrent with 1
Modify 1 Request is Queued
Enumerate 3 Request is Queued because of Modify Request
Enumerate 4 Request is Queued
Modify 2 Request is Queued
Enumerate 2 Finishes
Enumerate 1 Finishes
Modify 1 Starts because all in-progress at time of request Enumerators Finished
Modify 1 Finishes
Enumerate 3 Starts because Queued Modify 1 Finished
Enumerate 4 Starts
Enumerate 3 Finishes
Enumerate 4 Finishes
Modify 2 Starts
...
```

Comment: I guess you are not switch to ConcurrentDictionary, because it would require code changes - right?

Answer (score 2):

I had to implement a concurrent list recently, and you are welcome to try it out if it helps:

```
public class ConcurrentList<T> : IList<T>, IList
{
    private readonly List<T> underlyingList = new List<T>();
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> underlyingQueue;
    private bool requiresSync;
    private bool isDirty;

    public ConcurrentList()
    {
        underlyingQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    }

    public ConcurrentList(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        underlyingQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>(items);
    }

    private void UpdateLists()
    {
        if (!isDirty)
            return;
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            requiresSync = true;
            T temp;
            while (underlyingQueue.TryDequeue(out temp))
                underlyingList.Add(temp);
            requiresSync = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.ToList().GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (requiresSync)
            lock (syncRoot)
                underlyingQueue.Enqueue(item);
        else
            underlyingQueue.Enqueue(item);
        isDirty = true;
    }

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        if (requiresSync)
            lock (syncRoot)
                underlyingQueue.Enqueue((T)value);
        else
            underlyingQueue.Enqueue((T)value);
        isDirty = true;
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.IndexOf((T)value);
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.Contains((T)value);
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.IndexOf((T)value);
        }
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.Insert(index, (T)value);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.Remove((T)value);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }

    T IList<T>.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                UpdateLists();
                return underlyingList[index];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                UpdateLists();
                underlyingList[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get { return ((IList<T>)this)[index]; }
        set { ((IList<T>)this)[index] = (T)value; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.Clear();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.Contains(item);
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.CopyTo((T[])array, index);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                UpdateLists();
                return underlyingList.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return syncRoot; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            return underlyingList.IndexOf(item);
        }
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            UpdateLists();
            underlyingList.Insert(index, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be very careful when using this! It is impossible to enumerate this list safely, as the count can change out from underneath a reader. (Also, I'm not sure what you're doing with the ConcurrentQueue there; why do you need the requiresSync flag? ConcurrentQueue is always thread-safe.)

Answer (score 2):

The classic solution to the problem is reader-writer locks. With reader-writer locks, readers don't keep other readers from taking the lock, but writers block readers and other writers, so that they can safely make changes.

If you're using the TPL then you certainly have access to [System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx). Take a reader lock when enumerating the list, and take a writer lock when adding or removing items from the list. This will give you the "next level" of scalability on the list.

Comment: It was my understanding that this type of lock suffers from the issue I mentioned.  Do write requests get queued and come before read requests? Or do they just get starved out?

Comment: The ReaderWriterLockSlim class is "Fair", which is to say that once a writer begins to wait for the lock, further readers are blocked until the writer's request has been satisfied. So you don't have to worry about starvation.